# Debug logging in Factorio mod

Tags: modding

I'm writing a Factorio mod, and I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work. Can I do some kind of error / debug logging somewhere? Both manual (printing variables) and simple error reporting (accessing a property that doesn't exist) would be great. I know about the `player.print` method, but I can only get it to print string literals, not objects:

```
script.on_event(defines.events.on_player_created, function(event)
    pcall(function()
        local player = game.get_player(event.player_index)
        player.print("Hi player") -- works
        player.print(player) -- does not work. Any error message would be nice
    end)
end)
```

I've also tried the log file in the application folder, and the various debug modes (F5/F6 in game), but so far haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Perhaps you're assuming it will automatically generate a string from the object? You might need to create and explicitly use some kind of `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this forum post](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=23844)

> You can launch the game from console, so standard print function would send its output there. You can redirect that output to files.
>
> There is serpent pretty printer, which can print lua tables - syntax is `print(serpent.block(arg))`.

Comment: Sounds good, but it doesn't quite work. Running `factorio.exe` from the command prompt starts the game, but returns immediately and I only see the output of the first log line. Using `start factorio.exe /wait` doesn't work either, because it only opens a console window and doesn't start the game at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the error() function which sends to factorio-current.log

For example:

error("Hi player")

or

error(serpent_block(table_name))

Comment: serpent_block --> serpent.block

Comment: It actually shows an "error" popup with the message at the game loading and prevents the mod to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a write_file method in LuaGameScript.

```
game.write_file("mylog.log", serpent_block(table_name)) -- normal write
game.write_file("mylog.log", serpent_block(table_name), true) -- appending
```

(http://lua-api.factorio.com/0.15.23/LuaGameScript.html#LuaGameScript.write_file)

The file will end up in a folder called `script-output` under `%APPDATA%/Factorio`, next to your `scenarios` folder.

Comment: Does not seem to work from data.lua

Comment: data.lua is not a normal runtime script. Its purpose is to describe a data structure and nothing else. Most(all?) runtime objects are not accessible during it's interpretation. In particular the global LuaGameScript object called game does not even exist then.